# tinymce file browsers multiple file source

Tags: tinymce, file-browser

I am doing some updates to a site I have developed over the last few years. It has grown rather erratically (I tried to plan ahead, but with this site it has taken some odd turns).

Anyway, the site has a community blog ( blog.domain.com - used to be domainblog.com) ) and users with personal areas ( user1.domain.com, user2.domain.com, etc ).

The personal areas have standard page content that the user can use, or add snippets of text to partially customize. Now the owner wants the users to be able to create their own content.

Everything is done up to using a file browser.

I need a browser that will allow me to do the following:

- the browser needs to be able to browse the common files at blog.domain.com/files and the user files at user_x.domain.com/files
- the browser will also need to be able to differentiate between the two and generate the appropriate image url.
- of course, the browser access to the user files will need to be dynamic and only show those files particular to the user (along with the common files)
- I also need to be able to set a file size for images

the admin area is in a different directory than either the blog or the user subdomains.

general directory structure

--webdir--
    |--client --
            |--clientsite--
                |--blog (blog.domain.com)
                |--sites--
                    |--main site (domain.com)
                    |--admin (admin.domain.com)
                    |--users--
                        |--user1 (user1.domain.com)
                        |--user2 (user2.domain.com)
                        ...etc.

I have tried several different browsers and using symlinks but the browsers don't seem to be able to follow them. I am also having trouble even setting them to use a directory that isn't the default.

what browser would you recommend? what would I need to customize to make it work.

TIA

Comment: My only other option is to create a custom solution where I query the databases seperately and generate a list that the users will have to copy/paste the correct URL, but with 1000+ images will be somewhat cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, since I have not had any responses to this question, I guess I will have to do a work around and then see about writing a custom file browser down the road.